# MySQLi subscribe list table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a table called `users` and a table called `pages`. Users of the system can subscribe to a page and receive updates about the page. My problem is that users and pages will be updated dynamically (ie. no manual intervention to the tables) and I don't want to keep adding another column everytime someone subscribes to the page.

**How can I achieve updating both the users table and the pages table dynamically to reflect that they have subscribed to that page?**

My idea would be to add an comma separated array of usernames into the pages table and update them as users subscribe/unsubscribe.

Comment: assuming that a user can subscribe to more than 1 page, you'll need an intermediate table to gather the data. While comma separated array of usernames may work, it is bad practice since it does not comply with 3rd normal form of databases. Create a table like `users_pages`

Comment: That is a good idea Yani. I don't know why I didn't think of that before. That would solve the problem, thanks

Comment: I felt like answering, but frankly speaking, Yani provided the right answer already - not going to steal his rep...
Go ahead and post an answer Yani.

Comment: @PawelP thanks for being a sport my friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just making it an official answer:

While the initial hunch may be to use comma separated values to represent the link between those 2 tables (or any other way of saving the data in one column like saving a json string), it is actually bad practice because it does not conform to the First Normal Form (and definitely not 2nd and 3rd).

[First Normal Form - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

First Normal Form says you should never store more than 1 value in 1 table cell.

The problem, in short, starts when you'll need to use that data, which will actually take you at least 2 actions - 1 is reading the data from the database and 2nd is to parse it in your languaging script. Imagine what happens when you need then to use that data to read some other data from the database - you are making more sql queries than you need and taking at least twice the time (+resources). It becomes even more complicated when you need to use JOIN queries or have other one-to-many data relationships.

The solution then is simple - you need to create a 3rd table that serves as an intermediate table.
You can call it `users_pages` or `user2pages` and that represents the 1 to many relationship between 1 user and many pages.
The structure of the table is as simple as:

```
users_pages
-----------
-- id // a unique id for the relationship, can be auto generated
-- user_id // the user id
-- page_id // the page id
-----------
```

This allows you to build a more robust application as well as run advanced queries and calculations without the need to parse the data in your script (i.e count amount of pages each user is subscribed to, or amount of users subscribed to 1 page).

Unsubscribing can be also much easier this way since you don't need to read the users or pages table at all. You simply delete the relation from the `users_pages` table.
Without it, you will need to (a) first read the users table (b) get the pages data comma separated (c) parse the data and remove the specific page from it (d) save the new data again to the database. That's 4 actions and 2 SQL queries...

I hope this helps!